# How to merge 2 group by select statements

Tags: sql, merge, group-by, union

I have 2 tables, 1 for free users and 1 for paid users, they are both tracking clicks, I need to show for each affiliate link who are the referrers (domains), the user some of time may be a free user and some of the time can be a paid user, so I need to merge both stats from both tables.

this query doesn't work:

```
SELECT ref,COUNT(ref) AS clicks 
FROM click_analytics_free 
WHERE link_id = '$link_id'
GROUP BY ref 
UNION ALL
SELECT ref,COUNT(ref) AS clicks 
FROM click_analytics_paid 
WHERE link_id = '$link_id '
GROUP BY ref
```

Comment: Tag the DBMS that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `union all` and then aggregate again:

```
SELECT ref, SUM(free_clicks), SUM(paid_clicks), 
       SUM(free_clicks + paid_clicks)
FROM ((SELECT ref, COUNT(ref) AS free_clicks, 0 as paid_clicks
       FROM click_analytics_free
       WHERE link_id = ?
       GROUP BY ref
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT ref, 0, COUNT(ref) AS paid_clicks
       FROM click_analytics_paid
       WHERE link_id = ?
       GROUP BY ref
      )
     ) c
GROUP BY ref;
```

The `?` is a parameter placeholder.  Your code should be using parameters rather than munging query strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can do aggregation :

```
SELECT ref, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN flag = 'free' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS free_click,
       SUM(CASE WHEN flag = 'paid' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS paid_click
FROM (SELECT ref, 'free' as flag 
      FROM click_analytics_free 
      WHERE link_id = '$link_id '
      UNION ALL
      SELECT ref, 'paid' as flag 
      FROM click_analytics_paid 
      WHERE link_id = '$link_id'
     ) t
GROUP BY ref;
```